# Stop YouTube embed after clicking outside modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a certain button is clicked on my project, a modal opens up with two YouTube videos I embedded. The problem however is when I click outside this modal to close the modal the videos continue playing (whichever video is being played). I would like the video to stop playing when a user clicks outside the modal.

This is what i have tried

```
<a class="primary-btn text-uppercase" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#workshops">View</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="workshops" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">
                    A sample of some our workshops and tutorials
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="resp-container">
                    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-EX-zHVVSI8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="resp-container">
                    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bUPg5BZj7dY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <span onclick="stopVideo(this.getAttribute('vdoId'))" vdoId="resp-iframe" id="CloseModalButton" data-dismiss="modal"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function stopVideo(id){
        var src = $j('iframe.'+id).attr('src');
        $j('iframe.'+id).attr('src','');
        $j('iframe.'+id).attr('src',src);
    }
</script>
```

Right now I am getting a modal with only one of the videos I embedded and it is not stopping when I close the modal.

**Update** 
Based on the answer given this is what I have tried:

```
<script>
    $('#workshops').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        stopVideo("resp-iframe");
    });
</script>
```

I can no longer close the modal when I click the space outside the modal. This is the error message I am getting in my browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: stopVideo is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):564)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at r.t.hide (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
```

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap modals - which i assume you are using - have 2 events in place that are getting fired on closing. #1 `hide.bs.modal` #2 `hidden.bs.modal`. Have a look at the [full list of modal events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events)

So to run your stop function when closing your modal you would want to create a new eventhandler like so :

```
$('#workshops').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
  // Stop the videos as soon as the modal's hide function gets called
  stopVideo("resp-iframe"); // your id seems to be a static value you could ofcourse also use the value from your #CloseModalButton
});
```

Comment: not sure what i'm doing wrong but this isn't working. Granted I am a bit of a javascript amateur. Will update question with attempted solution

Comment: Well that can't work you are now declaring a function within a anonymous callback. You just want to use that function within that. I will update my Answer

Comment: That should not be the case, check your console [F12] you will now most likely have an error in your `stopVideo` function.

Comment: Well did you define it before ? The fact that I changed the function call within the event handler didn't mean that you do not need to declare that function.